# Google Drive get public file hash header without downloading the file or needing to authenticate

Tags: google-drive-api

You can get a direct download link to a public Google Drive file by sending a GET request to `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=`, with the `id` parameter populated of course, the direct download link will be provided in the `Location` header.

You're then able to download the file by sending a GET request to the direct download link. The files hash will be provided in the `X-Goog-Hash` header. Using this method means you must download the file to get its hash as it's provided in the direct download headers.

Does anyone know if there is an endpoint and or parameter combination that will allow me to get the files hash without having to download it? The method also needs to be publicly available without having to authenticate.

Comment: i doubt it google would rather you be doing this though the api with an api key so they can track you